# MS Excel: Find the First instance of Text after the First Instance of Test and Trim

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have the following data in the same cell as a list, cell Z2.

> Unit 1 Information
>
> Monthly Rent: $1,250
>
> Estimated Rent
>
> Appliances: Refrigerator, Range With Oven
>
> Combined Dining/Living Room
>
> No of Bedrooms : 2
>
> No of Bedrooms: 2
>
> No of Full Baths: 1
>
> No of Full Baths: 1

What I am trying to accomplish is to first search for Unit 1, and when Unit 1 is found, to return back the next instance of '# of Bedrooms : 2', and if that is not found search for next instance of '# of Bedrooms: 2' and just return '2'. Basically, I am trying parse and figure out the number of bedrooms associated with Unit 1.

I am using

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($AO$1,Z2)),1,0)
```

to identify if there is a 'Unit 1', but I can't seem to be able to then create a workable `IF` statement to pull the next instance of `No of Bedrooms`.  I have also tried index and row matches but since the data is contained in one cell.  It isn't possible.

```
=INDEX(B2:C14,SMALL(IF(B2:B14="Unit 1",ROW(B2:B14)-ROW(B2)+1,ROW(B14)+1),1),2)
```

Comment: I'm a litle bit confused. What is your desired output here exactly and why?

Comment: Explore FILTERXML() function. I am now on mobile so can't test your data. Can you show exact output you want from this single cell.

Comment: @jvdV - Using the sample above... 1. I would first like to find the first instance of 'Unit 1'. Once that is found I would like to search for 'No of Bedrooms :' first, and if that is not found, to then search for 'No of Bedrooms:' 3. If 'No of Bedrooms :' is found then return ' 2', but if No of Bedrooms :' is not found then it would return the value after 'No of Bedrooms:', which in this case is also ' 2.'

Comment: Right, and would this data always follow the same pattern? Also, what about false positives. Would you be worried if `Unit 1` is found in `Unit 11`?

Comment: 1. Not concerned about Unit 1 being Unit 11. The data after Unit 1 could be in a different order or include more/less data.  'Combined Dining / Living Room' could be in a different order, or not included. Regarding 'No of Bedrooms :' and / or 'No of Bedrooms:' 1 or both could be their, or neither.  In the case neither I'd want to include a false, using an IF ERROR. I am attempting to start with the following but believe I am going in the wrong direction, and then put IF's.         =RIGHT(Z2,LEN(B18)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(Z2,"# of Bedrooms :","~",1)))

Comment: What version of Excel have you got?

Comment: @JvdV. My Subscription is: Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise, and I am on version 16.0.13127.21062 32 - bit.

Comment: @Harun24HR, I would just want to see the number next to 'No of Bedrooms :' or 'No of Bedrooms:', in both cases in the above example I would want to see 2.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  The following works for what I am trying to accomplish.  Thank you for all the help!

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(MID(A1,FIND("Unit 1",A1),200),FIND("Bedrooms",MID(A1,FIND("Unit 1",A1),200)),12),"Bedrooms : ",""),"Bedrooms: ","")
```

Another option so you don't send up endless substitutes is to just use Right in the statement.

```
=RIGHT(MID(MID(A1,FIND("Unit 1",A1),200),FIND("Bedrooms",MID(A1,FIND("Unit 1",A1),200)),12),2)
```